# SQL calculation not showing in correct format

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL query that comes out at 700

```
declare @a decimal(10,0)
declare @b decimal(10,0)

set @a = 100 - 2 
set @a = @a / 14
set @a = @a * 100

set @a = ((100 - 2) / 14) * 100

select @a
```

What i am looking for it do is return 85.714285 etc...

Not quite sure where i going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: WHy do you expect the result to be 85.714285 ???

Comment: [BODMAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`700` is the correct result.

Please check again!

```
((100 - 2) / 14) * 100 = 700
```

You calculated that

```
100 - 2 / 14 * 100 = 85,...
```

You want to use this sql query.

```
set @a = 100 - 2.0 / 14 * 100
```

Comment: If you use windows calculator in standard mode and do 100-2 /14*100 it comes out at 700 however if you change it scientific it comes out at 85.714285714285714285714285714286 - the later is what i want as the result

Comment: then remove the `()` from your sql query like that: `set @a = 100 - 2.0 / 14 * 100`. And add a `.` to either `2` or `14`.

Comment: Thanks Juergen, Thats is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration is wrong:

```
declare @a decimal(10,0)
declare @b decimal(10,0)
```

You have specified the length, however not the number of decimals, which is done by using the second value.

Answer (score 0):

Add a .0 to the end of your last line, since if you use all integers SQL will implicitly cast the result as an int.

```
set @a = ((100 - 2) / 14) * 100.0
```

Answer (score 0):

change your declarations to include decimal places:

```
declare @a decimal(10,5)
declare @b decimal(10,5)

set @a = 100 - 2 
set @a = @a / 14
set @a = @a * 100

set @a = ((100 - 2) / 14) * 100

select @a
```

Since your declaration is set to `10,0` then you will get no decimal places.

if you want the answer to be 85.714... then you need to change your SQL to:

```
declare @a decimal(10,5)

set @a = 100.0 - 2.0 
set @a = @a / 14.0
set @a = @a * 100.0

set @a = 100.0 - ((2.0 / 14.0) * 100.0)

select @a
```

To get the result you are looking for you need to add a `.` to the other values (2, 14, etc) and you will get the value you want, you also need to make sure that your parentheses are in the correct location.

Results - 85.71430

Comment: That just returns 700.00000 - i need it to return 85.714285 etc

Comment: 700 is the correct result ((100-2)/14) *100 does not equal 85.714285

Comment: If you use windows calculator in standard mode and do 100-2 /14*100 it comes out at 700 however if you change it scientific it comes out at 85.714285714285714285714285714286 - the later is what i want as the result.