# SQL Gives Erroreneous Result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I was just going through a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226900/sql-calculation-not-showing-in-correct-format)

So I tried to calculate it myself and check the result..
But the result always I get is a rounded value. Why ??

Actually I should get **0.1428**......

[image]

**@Everyone who answered**: Thank you everyone, as per SO rules I can accept only one answer, so accepting the one who was earliest.

Comment: Of course, the bit that's only *implied* by all of the answers is that, when SQL Server is evaluating an operation, it only considers the data types involved in that operation. It doesn't evaluate the type of the variable/column which will *receive* the result of that calculation. (Which appears to be partially what you were expecting)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Explicit statements--"the data types involved in that operation" and "It doesn't evaluate the type of the variable/column which will receive the result of that calculation." Makes more sense ! Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try that

```
select 2.0 / 14
```

If you use integers the result will be integer too. integers are not floating point numbers

Answer (score 2):

The result of the integer division `2/14` is always 0.

Try `2.0/14.0` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html).

At least one of the operands needs to be a float/decimal in order for the whole expression to evaluate to one of those types.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
declare @a float
set @a = 2.0/14.0
select a=@a
```

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT 2.0/14`

Need to decimal place to "trigger" the floating point

Comment: 5 answers! I need to type faster :(